# isometric quadratic spaces over a prime field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Let $(V, \gamma)$ be a quadratic space, where $V$ is an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{Z}/(7)$-vector space and $r = r(\gamma)$ is the rank of the bilinear form.

I want to show: either, $(V, \gamma)$ is isometric to $(V, \gamma')$, where $\gamma'$ is given by the associated matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
        E_r & 0 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

or, it's isometric to $(V, \gamma'')$, where $\gamma''$ is given by the associated matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
        E_{r-1} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 6 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

where $E_m$ is the identity matrix of size $m$.

Thanks in advance. I thought that this might be solved via induction over $r$, but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: I would try the following. 1) Show that $\gamma$ is diagonalizable. 2) Show that any diagonal entry $d$ can be replaced with $d s^2$ for some $s\neq0$, so you can replace all the squares with a $1$ and all the non-squares with $-1$ ($7\equiv-1\pmod4$ so $-1$ is a non-square). 3) Then show that a pair of $-1$s can replaced with a pair of $+1$s. The first step is explained in many a book (IIRC Lidl & Niederreiter has it, but I cannot check now). The others are  nice exercises. IIRC step three uses the fact that we can find elements $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}_7$ such that $a^2+b^2=-1$.